# How do I update object data after editing a DataGridView cell when the DataGridView is bound to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

first time poster. Sorry if the code I post is poorly formatted or hard to interpret.

I am trying to figure out how to update the object property data I have in a class object "AnalogInput" located in a DataGridView that has it's DataSource property set to a DataTable. So, after I edit a cell in the DataGridView, I would like to send that updated value back to the DataTable and thus the AnalogInput property value.

I am trying to do this in a WinForms application.

Below is some code that sums up pretty much where I am at right now:

Create a DataGridView to display some select and editable AnalogInput properties

```
DataGridView dataGridView_AnalogPoints = new dataGridView();
```

Create a new instance of a class object "AnalogInput" with public string properties initialized as shown below

```
AnalogInput point = new AnalogInput() { Name = "Something", Address = "2", Minimum = "-32768", Maximum = "32767"};
```

Create a new DataTable to hold the desired properties of the object "AnalogInput"

```
DataTable analogPoints = new DataTable();
```

Add the columns to the DataTable

```
analogPoints.Columns.Add("Name");
analogPoints.Columns.Add("Address");
analogPoints.Columns.Add("Minimum");
analogPoints.Columns.Add("Maximum");
```

Add the object data into a new row in the DataTable analogPoints

```
analogPoints.Rows.Add(point.Name, point.Address, point.Minimum, point.Maximum);
```

Set the source of the dataGridView.

```
dataGridView_AnalogPoints.DataSource = analogPoints;
```

So, once I edit the DataGridView cell that contains the object data from the DataSource as DataTable, which gets it's data from the AnalogInput object, how can I update it to the newly entered value from the DataGridView? I feel like I'm pretty far off from achieving this.

I only have about 9 months worth of experience working with C# and WinForms so I apologize if my code looks messy. I'm also not sure what I should be searching for specifically to solve this.

Comment: Either loop through the `DataTable` rows and create the “new” `AnalogInput` objects, OR, instead of creating a `DataTable`… make a `List` of `AnalogInput` objects (`List<AnalogInput>`) and use that as a `DataSource` to the grid. Without more information it is difficult to say how you should do this. Is the data in a data base?

Comment: I am retrieving each `AnalogInput` from a `List<AnalogInput>` that ultimately belongs to a class object `Device`. So retrieving this list would look something like `myDevice.Inputs.Analog`. The user selects a `Device` by selecting a `TreeNode`, then that is supposed to populate the `DataGridView` with the `List<AnalogInput>` from that `Device`.

Comment: If you already have a `List<AnalogInput>` then use that list as a data source to the grid. Example: `List<AnalogInput> data = myDevice.Inputs.Analog; dataGridView_AnalogPoints.DataSource = data;`. I am guessing there is more to this than you are showing.

Comment: If I set the data source that way how do I populate the `DataGridView` with rows containing the properties that I want to allow to be displayed _and_ edited from the `DataGridView` belonging to each `AnalogInput` from `myDevice.Inputs.Analog`? From the example I want the properties of each `AnalogInput`: `public string Name { get; set;}`,`public string Address { get; set;}`,`public string Minimum { get; set;}`, and `public string Maximum { get; set;}` to be displayed in the `DataGridView` columns I defined in the example.

Comment: I am not following what you are asking. If you have a `List<AnalogInput>` which “contains” multiple `AnalogInput` objects in the list, then, setting this list as a data source to the grid should display such that the first column will be “Name”, the second column will be “Address” etc.… then “each” row in the grid will represent “one” `AnalogInput` object in the list.

Comment: If you make a “change” to one of the cells in the grid, then this will automatically be reflected in the `List<AnalogInput>`. If the initial `List<AnalogInput>` contains ALL the different devices… then you will need to “filter” the list to show only the devices you want. Again, I am guessing there is more to this than you are showing.

Comment: Right, thank you! It is correctly displaying now and it did update correctly as well. However I only want the specified fields to be displayed in 4 columns from my last comment: Name, Address, Minimum, and Maximum. Currently all of the fields get displayed and throw errors because there are uninitialized fields in the class object that don't need to be displayed.

Comment: If you only want to display specific properties… then add the columns to the grid manually, in this case 4 columns. Make sure each column’s `DataPropertyName` MATCHES one of the property names you want to display in the `AnalogInput` object. Then before setting the grids data source set the grids `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`.

Comment: You are a saint. It worked! Thank you so much my dude, I really appreciate it! This makes things a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are very far from achieving your intended behaviour. The DataGridView class has a wonderful event called CellValueChanged. In case you don't know what events are, think of them like a case that a developer believes may happen (like value changed, control clicked, mouse hover etc.) that s/he wants to allow you to subscribe methods to be invoked whenever the case occurs.
What you wish to do is run a function whenever a value of a cell was changed. To subscribe a method to an event you need to write the following line of code:

```
objectInstanceName.EventName += MethodName; // subscribes a method to be invoked when event occurs
```

This is not necessarily relevant for your case here, but if you no longer want a method that you have previously subscribed to be invoked, you can unsubscribe it with the following line of code:

```
objectInstanceName.EventName -= MethodName; // unsubscribes a method to cancel it from being invoked when event occurs
```

You can also subscribe as many methods as you wish for an event. Note that every event expects the methods subscribed to it have a specified return type, amount of parameters and their type (those are specified by a thing called a delegate).

In order to create a method that matches the expected return type and parameters you can press TAB twice right after typing the += and visual studio will automatically generate a method for you, or write the method's name and then hover on it with the mouse, open the suggestions menu and click "Generate method".

The CellValueChanged event "wants" its subscribed methods to have the following parameters (their names don't matter, what matters is their order and type):

```
object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e
```

The parameter **sender** is the object caused the method to be invoked (i.e your DataGridView) and **e** is of type DataGridViewCellEventArgs, which has some properties that'll be very helpful for you: RowIndex, and ColumnIndex. Using those parameters you can simply update the values of your DataTable and also your actual AnalogPoint instance in case you assigned it to some object.